# Python: Scraping Selenium / Nested Loop

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm currently training on web scraping. To do so, I'm trying to get a list of usernames of people having liked a post. So far, I've write a script that works with small lists of usernames (below 100) and it's still not reliable because I think that the platforms is detecting the automation...

Here is my code: ('https://www.instagram.com/p/BuT_u-UAKn1/')

```
# Locating the likers' list
userid_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/section[2]/div/div/a')[0].click()
time.sleep(2)

# Getting the number of likes on the given post
likes = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/span/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/section[2]/div/div/a/span').text
no_space = likes.replace(' ','')
int_likes = int(no_space)
print(int_likes)

# Getting the actual list of users
users = []

height = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div").value_of_css_property("padding-top")
match = False
while match==False:
    lastHeight = height

    # step 1
    elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id]/div/a")

    # step 2
    for element in elements:
        if element.get_attribute('title') not in users:
            users.append(element.get_attribute('title'))

    # step 3
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", elements[-1])
    time.sleep(0.1)

    # step 4
    height = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div").value_of_css_property("padding-top")
    if int_likes == len(users) and lastHeight==height:
        match = True

print(users)
print(len(users))
driver.quit()
```

The problem is that I received this error:

> StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of  is stale; either the element is no longer
>   attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the
>   document has been refreshed

So I would like to add a condition that says "when the loops stop loading and the lenght of the users' list is not equal to int_likes, break, wait a few seconds, scroll up a little bit (like 400 pixels) and then restart the process again, until it meets requirements".

But I'm having a hard time putting this logic into actual code... Would you guys could help me on this?

Thanks